# Замена символов кириллицы на латиницу

Tags: windows, текст, кириллица, преобразование

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы в реальном времени при вводе букв с клавиатуры определённые буквы заменялись на другие?

Пример:
к = k, з = z,м = m, ф = f, Д = D, Л = L, Г = G.
Пробовал сделать, используя AHK — не получилось.

Чтобы теkст получался вот таkиm. ИСКАL МНОGO разной инfормации, но таk и не смог понять. :(

Comment: Зависит от того, на каком языке и для какого окружениия (консоль, браузер, почтовая программа и т.п.) вы хотите это сделать

Comment: Среда windows в целом, чтобы при печатном вводе происходила замена символов.

Comment: [ремапим клавиатуру](https://habr.com/ru/post/125298/)

Comment: @Daemon-5, это немного не то, что мне нужно. Используя твой метод при наборе буквы R я буду получать букву K, что мне не нужно. 
Простой ремаппинг не учитывает мою раскладку, а значит, он работает на обеих, не позволяя выполнить то, что мне нужно :(

Используя утилиты из поста при наборе латиницей у меня будет так:
R = K, A = F, V = m etc. Это абсолютно не то, что хотелось бы.